# Excel Index Match - List All Results

Tags: excel

I am using the following Index Match function to get the name of a company where the spend data matches that of which I type into cell BF17.

```
=INDEX($AM$16:$BB$16,MATCH(BF17,AM17:BB17,0))
```

What I want to be able to do is list multiple results within the same cell and separate these with a comma.

Does anyone know if this is possible and if so can someone please show me how?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a formula based solution? That's difficult to do with results listed in one cell, simpler with results listed in separate cells, e.g. either down a column or across a row

Answer (score 0):

## Code:

Insert this code in a module in your workbook:

```
Public Function hLookupList(KeyVal, Vals As Range, Ret As Range) As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim vw As Worksheet
    Dim rw As Worksheet
    Dim RetStr As String
    
    Application.Volatile True
    
    Set vw = Vals.Worksheet
    Set rw = Ret.Worksheet
    
    If Vals.Rows.Count > 1 Then
        hLookupList = "Too Many Value Rows Selected!"
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    If Ret.Rows.Count > 1 Then
        hLookupList = "Too Many Return Rows Selected!"
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    If Vals.Columns.Count <> Ret.Columns.Count Then
        hLookupList = "Value Range and Return Range must be the same size!"
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    
    For i = Vals.Column To Vals.Column + Vals.Columns.Count - 1
        If vw.Cells(Vals.Row, i) = KeyVal Then
            RetStr = RetStr & rw.Cells(Ret.Row, Ret.Column + i - 1) & ", "
        End If
    Next i
    
    hLookupList = Left(RetStr, Len(RetStr) - 2)
End Function
```

Then:
Insert this in the cell where you want your list: `=hLookupList(BF17, $AM$16:$BB$16, $AM$17:$BB$17)`

Comment: thanks but I tried this and it gives me a #name? error

Comment: I'd have to see your data, but it worked on a test workbook for me.  The only reason this would return that error is if you added the formula to the cell and then renamed the Module or deleted/moved the module to another workbook.

Comment: where abouts are you placing the vba code? can I place this in my workbook instead of in a module? and if so would I need to place it under a sub?

Comment: Function definitely should be in a module.  Just paste my code into an empty module in your workbook.  And make sure that it's in the correct workbook (I make that mistake quite often.)

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately there is no built-in way to make a vlookup or index/match function return an array. You could do it with a custom formula or if you know there are a limited number of results, a few nested lookups. Lewiy at mrexcel.com wrote a great custom function that I use, which can be found [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/280705-vlookup-return-multiple-values-one-cell-concatenate.html). This function can be slow if you are looking up a large number of rows.

Since you are looking up columns and want commas separating the results instead of spaces, you will need to modify the code as follows:

```
Function MYVLOOKUP(lookupval, lookuprange As Range, indexcol As Long)
Dim r As Range
Dim result As String
result = ""
For Each r In lookuprange
    If r = lookupval Then
        result = result & "," & r.offSet(indexcol, 0)
    End If
Next r
result = Right(result, Len(result) - 1)
MYVLOOKUP = result
End Function
```

Your formula would then be =MYVLOOKUP(BF17,AM17:BB17,-1)
If you want a space after the comma (in the results), change:

```
result = result & "," & r.offSet(indexcol, 0)
```

to

```
result = result & ", " & r.offSet(indexcol, 0)
```

If you haven't used custom functions before, hit Alt + F11 when in Excel to bring up the VBE, and add a new module to the workbook you are working on (Insert --> Module). Just copy and paste this code in there. I would recommend Paste Special --> Values before sending the workbook to anyone. Let me know if you have any questions implementing it!

Comment: He actually needed an hLookup not a vLookup judging by the formula he was using.

Comment: True, I forgot to change the name of the function, but it actually runs an Hlookup. The vlookup that Lewiy had switched the offSet(indexcol, 0) to offSet(0, indexcol-1).